# Why does the iRobot Create 3 slow down at the end of a Drive Goal (straight)?

Tags: ros, ros2

Without changes too much and using default settings, why does the iRobot Create 3 slow before stopping?

Is there a way to stop this behavior to abruptly stop at the end of the goal?

Below is the Drive goal parameters that I am sending.

```
    def sendDriveGoal(self, dist): 
        self.status = GoalStatus.STATUS_EXECUTING
        goal = DriveDistance.Goal()
        goal.distance = 0.4*float(dist)
        goal.max_translation_speed = 0.2
        self.get_logger().info('Waiting for action server...')  
        self._drive_client.wait_for_server()

        self._send_goal_future = self._drive_client.send_goal_async(goal, feedback_callback = self.feedback_callback)
        self.get_logger().info('Driving...\n\n')
        self._send_goal_future.add_done_callback(self.goal_response_callback)
```